# How to calculate coordinate system from one vector?

Tags: c++, math, vector, coordinate-systems

How to create coordinate system given only a vector?
*(left-handed, right-handed, local or different space)*

[image]

I'm searching calculate a local coordiante system algorithm given only one vector:

Reason:

1) Maybe Z is surface normal, then X and Y vector would be tangent and bitangent vector

2) Another reason is for ray tracing: sampling a light source. Given a intersection point construct local coordinate system from that point then trace ray to light shape.

```
Vector3 Z = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; // given
// fill x and y
CreateXHandedCoordinateSystem(Vector3* X, Vector3* Y, const Vector3& Z) {
   // implementation goes here..
   // evaluate algorithm
   // calculate X
   // Y = cross(X, Z) or something ..
}
```

Comment: I sincerly have no idea what you want to know...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there does not appear to be a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the smallest component (in absolute value) of the given vector is `Zz`. Then define `X` to be `(Zy, -Zx, 0)`, and `Y = (-Zx.Zz, -Zy.Zz, Zx²+Zy²)`.

If the smallest component isn't `Zz`, adapt the formulas accordingly.

Notice that these vectors are unnormalized and I didn't look at handedness.

Comment: It would be nice to hear some more details, e.g. why `(Zy, -Zx, 0)` is orthogonal.

Comment: @PatrickStalph Vectors are orthogonal can be shown by computing X dot Z, X dot Y and Y dot Z and seeing that these are all zero. For example, X dot Z = Zx*Zy - Zy*Zx = 0. Also it can be easily checked that X cross Y points in the negative Z direction so if you want a right handed coordinate system you have to switch X and Y.

Comment: @PatrickStalph I should have said "If you want a right handed coordinate system you could, for example, switch X and Y." Using "have to" was too strong here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use double cross product trick.

1. Take your vector (lets call it local X) take arbitrary up vector (usually world up vector ) and calculate cross product. This will be your local Z.
2. Take your local X and local Z and calculate cross product this will be your local Y

Comment: Note that the cross product with an arbitrary up vector `[0,0,1]` can be zero, if the given `Z=[0, 0, 1]` is that same vector. In that case you have to pick another axis to start against.

Answer (score -1):

Just use coordinate rotation concept.

Initially, you have one vector (suppose in x direction)

Now rotate that vector by 90 degree and you will get the second axis (y axis if rotated 90 degree in XY plane)

Similarly get the third axis by rotating in appropriate plane.

Comment: Thanky you Bibek. I added some info to clear my question. How to rotate vector by 90 degree.(with dot product)? if I know vector z, how to calculate y or x vector with some math and code. if I find y or z, cross products give me other vector. I know cross product of two vector creates perpendicular vector. .

Comment: dot product wouldn't be needed, you just rotate the point and recalculate the vector